# Windows 10 - Focus on window if already open

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, user-interface

I am doing web developing and, of course, that means opening a lot of Windows very often.

Tends to mean I have tons of the same File Explorer windows open that are the same folder.

Is there a way to automatically focus on a Window instead of opening a new one?

I did look but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Where are these new windows coming from? Are you opening them yourself? Is the program you use opening them? If you're opening them yourself, you can click on an already open window to use that instead.

Comment: I'm opening them, yes. But I have so many open it takes long to see which I have open and I have to do it so often.

Comment: How are you opening them? When I click on a file explorer icon and a window is already open, it'll open that one by default.

Comment: I have them pinned in different places like the Start Menu.

Comment: Surely, if you open one you also get an icon for it on your start bar. Why don't just just click that or alt+tab to it?

Comment: Perhaps you could try opening the entire folder in your favorite editor (I like [atom](https://atom.io/)) and then opening your files from there (It has a little file explorer thing on the right [like this](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/isaacdfa35d7c9be66ddaeac5c4b4ccc2bde1.png)). You can access the files in your browser by entering their path, or going to whatever hostname the program you use to host them gives them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the order of the items pinned to your taskbar, you can press (windows key) + (a number) to bring that application's window to the foreground.

For example, if you have Chrome, VS Code, and Slack (in that order) pinned, windows + 1 will open Chrome, Windows + 2 will open Code, and Windows + 3 will open Slack.

This will not open a new window (unless the application is not already running), but you can also use Shift + Windows + Number to open a new window of the application.